# Почему form request laravel так отрабатывает?

Tags: laravel

Использую `form request` в `rules` пишу:
`'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'`
Почему мне выводит сообщение `The photo must be an image.`  ?
Как сделать что бы это поле было не обязательное, но при выборе что бы отрабатывали эти проверки ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `nullable` :

```
'photo' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.